# When to check internet connection in Mobile Applications

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone-8, connection

I would like to know recommended and best practices of checking internet connection in mobile applications.

In most of the apps I developed with my team mates, we check the internet connection before any action that requires internet connection. But I see many applications that notifies when device is disconnected from internet.

I would like to get a clear understanding about this topic and I believe so many developers like me hesitate about how to make this check properly when they are developing an application.

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Ideally, your app should monitor the phone network connectivity. Your app may or may not choose to act on connectivity changes. For iOS you can monitor the network connectivity by using [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code provided by Apple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use broadcast reciever to handle wifi changes.

Reciever code:

```
private BroadcastReceiver WifiStateChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int extraWifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

        switch (extraWifiState) {
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED: {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(DATA_DISCONNECTED);
            }
            break;
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING: {
            }
            break;
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED: {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(DATA_CONNECTED);
            }
            break;
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING: {
            }
            break;
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN: {
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Registering reciever:

```
this.registerReceiver(this.WifiStateChangedReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

To check mobile data connection changes You can use TelephonyManager:

```
PhoneStateListener pslCell = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED: {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(DATA_DISCONNECTED);
                }
                break;
                case TelephonyManager.DATA_SUSPENDED: {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(DATA_CONNECTED);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(pslCell, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
```

I recommend You to store network status in static variables. Also You need to check network status every application start.

Answer (score 2):

It is always related to the project We are doing.
If you are only doing the application which requires only internet connection at the time of any action then checking internet connection before perfoming the action is better it will remove the overhead of checking internet Connection every time
I prefer this method

But if we really requires full net connection every time if we need to load the latest news or chat applications we need to notify at every time.
For this we have to use the Appropriate Connection Api of every Mobile Platform
Android Provides Connection BroadCast Recivers For this

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends upon your Applications requirements that what kind of your Application is.

**Some times:**

**1)** We have to check the internet connection before any action that requires it.

**2)** We periodically check the internet connection after some specific defined interval.

**3)** We need immediate response of internet connection's status, so our App continuously checking it out and immediately send us notification status of internet failure or success, so we are able to tackle our App in such scenario.

Hope it helps.